# Is there a way to retrieve a comment on an answer that the answerer deleted on Quora?

Tags: quora

On Quora, the author of an answer may delete any comment left on their answer. Is there a way for a user to retrieve their comment on an answer that the answer's author deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as of now there is no way to retrieve comment if answer's author has deleted the comment.